# Comparing a range to a value doesn't result in an array when used inside SUM()

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

There is something about the `SUM()` function in Excel that I do not understand.

I can sum a range, like this: `=SUM(A2:A4)`.

I can sum a list of ranges: `=SUM(A2, A3:A4)`.

I can sum an array: `=SUM({1, 2, 3})` (returns `6`).

I can sum an array of non-numeric booleans by coercing the elements into numbers like so:

`=SUM(-{TRUE,TRUE,TRUE})` (returns `-3`).

**BUT**, the following won't work, and I don't know why:

`=SUM(--(A2:A7>0.5))`

By *won't work* I mean the result is either an error message, `0` or `1`. I was anticipating the result to work like a `COUNTIF()` function, where the result would report the number of instances in `A2:A7` whose value > 0.5.

My understanding was that `--(A2:A7>0.5)` should return an array, or so I thought.

For example, using `SUMPRODUCT()`, which accepts ranges or arrays, I can do `=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A4, B2:B4, --(A2:A4>0.5))` and the result will be the sumproduct of those columns where the value in column `A` > 0.5.

I am aware of `SUMIFS()` and I'm not looking for a solution. I'm just curious and looking for some explanation as to what something like `--(a2:a7>0.5)` actually returns, and why the `SUM()` function cannot handle it.

Comment: What do you mean by *won't work*?  What do you expect to happen?  It seems to work fine here, returning a count of all those entries in `a2:a7` where the value is `> 0.5`.  Since it is an array (and not an array constant as in your other example), you do have to confirm the formula by holding `ctrl` + `shift` while you hit `enter`

Comment: Sometimes `=sum(--(a2:a7>0.5))` will return an error, sometimes a 1, sometimes a 0. In fact, the exact same formula is giving a 1 in one cell, and a 0 in another. I don't have any insight into why . I will edit my question to make clear the result I expect, which you pointed out.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Sorry, but "confirming the formula" is not what array entering does, nor does it explain why it is required for `SUM()` but not for `SUMPRODUCT()`. See my answer for the full explanation.

Comment: @robinCTS You are quibbling about semantics (meaning of confirm), and although your observations are correct, it has merely to do with the fact that `SUM` was not designed to work with multi-cellular arrays directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This all stems from what happens when you use a multi-cell range in a formula where a single cell/value is expected. When you do so, Excel uses the single cell in the multi-cell range corresponding to the row of the cell that the formula is entered in, if the range is a column (or part thereof), or the cell corresponding to the column of the formula's cell if the range is a row (or part thereof). **It does *not* return an array.**

If there is no corresponding row/column or if a two dimensional range is supplied, then `#VALUE!` is used instead.

So, for example, if you enter the formula `=--(A2:A7>0.5)` in `C5`, Excel will evaluate it as `=--(A5>0.5)`, since comparisons normally take single values and you supplied a multi-cell range. If you enter the formula in `A9`, it will evaluate as `=--(#VALUE!>0.5)`.

Now, since `SUM()` can take either multi-cell ranges/arrays ***or*** single cells/values as arguments, coupled with the fact that comparisons are normally between single values they return a single value, Excel evaluates `=SUM(--(A2:A7>0.5))` as `=SUM(--(A5>0.5))` (when entered in anywhere in `$5:$5`, of course).

This is why you will get either a `0` or `1` (or the error if the corresponding cell in `$A:$A` contains an error) if the formula is entered anywhere in `$2:$7`, and a `#VALUE!` error otherwise (since `=SUM(--(#VALUE!>0.5))` evaluates to `#VALUE!`).

The reason why `=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A4, B2:B4, --(A2:A4>0.5))` works is because `SUMPRODUCT()` is designed to work with multi-cell range/array arguments. (It *will* still work with single cells/values/single valued arrays, though.) As such, it treats comparisons as multi-valued with an array result.

---

There are two methods to make `SUM()` work in the desired fashion:

**1. The `INDEX()` Method**

This method uses the fact that `INDEX()` expects a multi-cell range as the first argument, and that `INDEX(array,0)` (or my preferred `INDEX(array,)`) returns the entire array. Thus the comparison in `INDEX(--(A2:A7>0.5),)` is multi-valued and `=SUM(INDEX(--(A2:A7>0.5),))` works as desired.

**2. The Array Formula Method**

The comparison and other operators can be forced to be treated as multi-valued by entering the formula `=SUM(--(A2:A7>0.5))` as an array formula. This is done using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd> when inputting the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed  `=(a2:a7>0.5)` will return an array of values.

The array elements will be `TRUE` or `FALSE` or an error if the cell contains an error.

`--(a2:a7>0.5)` will return an array of `1`, `0` or the error if applicable.

`sum(--(a2:a7>0.5)`, when entered normally, will return different values depending on the location of the formula relative to a2:a7.  That value will be either `1`, `0`, the error message within the array, or the `#VALUE!` error.

`sum(--(a2:a7>0.5)` when entered as an array formula, by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>, will display the sum of the array.  However, if the array contains an error, then the formula will return the error.

Comment: Hmm. Every paragraph is either completely wrong or contains an error. (One is trivial though ;-) ) 1) Completely wrong. `=(A2:A7>0.5)` does ***not*** return an array. You can see this for yourself by using the "Evaluate Formula" tool. 2) The **single value** result will be either `FALSE`, `TRUE`, the corresponding cell error, **or `#VALUE!`**. See my answer for the why. 3) Ditto, with `0` and `1` instead of `FALSE` and `TRUE`. …

Comment: … 4) I lied ;-) This paragraph is *technically* correct, if you assume that by "array" you mean `A2:A7` and not the result of `--(A2:A7>0.5)`. (And yes, I'm aware of, and ignoring the missing `)` typo ;-) ) 5) Technically, this should read "… if the array contains **any errors**, then the formula will return the **first** error." (Ditto for the typo.)

Comment: @robinCTS You need to better understand some of the limitations of Excel. `=(A2:A7>0.5)` certainly does return an array.  However, if you enter it as a non-array formula, the `Evaluate Formula` tool will not show it. However, you can easily confirm the presence of an array by placing your cursor in the formula bar and selecting `F9`.  You can also return the individual elements with a formula such as `=INDEX(A2:A7>0.5,5,1)` entered normally.

Comment: @robinCTS the other paragraphs of my answer are also correct.

Comment: @robinCTS and, as you point out in your response, you can also coerce an array in the Evaluate Formula tool by wrapping with the INDEX function, or even the `SUMPRODUCT`

Comment: They way I understood it, pressing `F9` doesn't accurately reflect what actually happens in the cell. It always treats operations on multi-cell ranges as array-based and it doesn't calculate circular references the same way. Do you have a source that says otherwise?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77374/discussion-between-ron-rosenfeld-and-robincts).